# And operator in Selenium findByXpath is not working

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This works fine

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='dummyid' or @class='man-add']"));
```

But and operator is not working.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='dummyid' and @class='man-add']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='dummyid' | @class='man-add']"));
```

Comment: what error you got? give the relevant html part..

Answer (score 10):

You can't use `|` for a logical-or, you need to use `or`.  You can indeed use `and` for logical-and (but of course not `&`).  You didn't supply the HTML you're trying to run this against, so we can only guess, but based on experience I'd assume the `class` attribute has more than just `man-add` in it.  If so, you want something more like `//span[@id='dummyid' and contains(@class, 'man-add')]`.